# I'm new to Android App development and keep encountering the following error after following a tutorial I keep getting errors

Tags: android, xml

Here's the tutorial I've been using, I'm extremely new to this

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

I keep getting these errors

Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_behavior' in package 'com.example.(myname).mynewapp'

Error:(9, 26) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_behavior' with value '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior').

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users(myname)\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Here's my code

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
   tools:showIn="@layout/activity_my">
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />
</LinearLayout>`
```

Thank you so much to anyone who figures this out

Comment: fixed the code, it was incorrect at first

Comment: Did you add the design support library in your build.gradle?

Comment: Probably not, how do I do that?

Comment: `layout_behavior` only works for direct children of a `CoordinatorLayout` you don't seem to have that in your layout.  You might want to follow a different tutorial... or look at one of the many sample apps using features from the design library.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your dependencies in your app module's build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
```

Instead of 23.1.0 use whichever version you are using in your project.

Comment: How do I check my version?

Comment: Your build.gradle should already have `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'`. Use the same version number.